# Error when connecting Cygnus and STH

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus, fiware-sth-comet

I am trying to connect Cygnus and `STH`. I have a Cygnus instance in a container docker and a `STH` instance in a VM.

When I send a notification to Cygnus, available at `fiware-cygnus/cygnus-ngsi/resources/ngsi-examples/notification-json-simple.sh` it shows me the following error:

*NOTE: I replaced the STH IP to post the question*

> time=2017-03-06T17:35:46.522Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=0767a9d2-d44e-4872-9ef4-b57d68ef7f88 | trans=0767a9d2-d44e-4872-9ef4-b57d68ef7f88 | srv=red | subsrv=/red/red | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=processRollbackedBatches | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink[394] : Persistence error. Message: -, Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches PrimaryServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message}, caused by {java.net.SocketException: Connection reset}}], Stack trace: [com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISTHSink.persistOne(NGSISTHSink.java:158), com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISTHSink.persistBatch(NGSISTHSink.java:93), com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processRollbackedBatches(NGSISink.java:387), com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:370), org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68), org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147), java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)]
>       time=2017-03-06T17:35:46.522Z | lvl=INFO | corr=0767a9d2-d44e-4872-9ef4-b57d68ef7f88 | trans=0767a9d2-d44e-4872-9ef4-b57d68ef7f88 | srv=red | subsrv=/red/red | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=doRollbackAgain | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink[458] : Rollbacking again (0767a9d2-d44e-4872-9ef4-b57d68ef7f88), this was retry #9

And nothing is posted in STH.

In my agent.conf (cygnus conf) I have this:

```
cygnus-ngsi.sources = http-source
cygnus-ngsi.sinks = sth-sink
cygnus-ngsi.channels = sth-channel

cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.channels = sth-channel
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.port = 5050
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = default
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = /
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.NGSIGroupingInterceptor$Builder
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /opt/apache-flume/conf/grouping_rules.conf


cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISTHSink
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.channel = sth-channel
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.enable_encoding = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.enable_grouping = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.enable_name_mappings = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.enable_lowercase = false
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.data_model = dm-by-entity
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.mongo_hosts = <STH-MONGO-IP>:27017
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.mongo_username =
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.mongo_password =
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.db_prefix = sth_
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.collection_prefix = sth_
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.resolutions = day,hour,minute
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.batch_size = 1
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.batch_timeout = 30
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.batch_ttl = 10
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.data_expiration = 0
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.ignore_white_spaces = true


cygnus-ngsi.channels.sth-channel.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.channels.CygnusMemoryChannel
cygnus-ngsi.channels.sth-channel.capacity = 1000
cygnus-ngsi.channels.sth-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

And my STH config is:

```
var config = {};

// STH server configuration
//--------------------------
config.server = {

  host: '10.0.2.15',

  port: '8666',


  defaultService: 'testservice',


  defaultServicePath: '/testservicepath',


  filterOutEmpty: 'true',

  aggregationBy: ['day', 'hour', 'minute'],

  temporalDir: 'temp'
};

// Database configuration
//------------------------
config.database = {

  dataModel: 'collection-per-entity',
 user: '',

  password: '',

  URI: 'localhost:27017',

  replicaSet: '',

  prefix: 'sth_',


  collectionPrefix: 'sth_',

  poolSize: '5',


  shouldStore: 'both',
  truncation: {


    expireAfterSeconds: '0',
    size: '0',

    max: '0'
  },

  ignoreBlankSpaces: 'true',
  nameMapping: {

    enabled: 'false',

    configFile: './name-mapping.json'
  },

  nameEncoding: 'false'
};

// Logging configuration
//------------------------
config.logging = {
  level: 'info',
  NODE_ENV variable is set to 'development'.

  format: 'pipe',


  proofOfLifeInterval: '60'
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: This seems a network error, more specifically, the MongoDB driver is not able to reach the server to are specifying in Cygnus configuration. Are you running Cygnus locally to MongoDB? Or are both pieces in different machines?

Comment: Hello, I am running both pieces in different machines. Actually, I am running Cygnus into a container (docker) and the STH (and its MongoDB) into a VM CentOS 6. I already change the iptables configuration to allow access to 27017, but it is not working.

Comment: @frb, I got the connection right now. I just edited my `/etc/mongod.conf` and I commented out the `bindip=127.0.0.1` line. Now, I have a problem with authentication, but more easy to solve. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem:  I just edited my `/etc/mongod.conf` and I commented out the `bindip=127.0.0.1` to listen on all interfaces.